# Remove pause after first keypress with raw input

Tags: input, raw-input

I'm using RAWINPUT to handle the input in a C++ application. However, after the a key on the keyboard is pressed and the corresponding WM_ message has been sent, keyboard messages seems to pause for a half second before resuming without any pause between subsequent messages.

How can I change the repeat delay?

Here is the code is am using:

I forward the input from my message proc:

```
case WM_INPUT:
    if (!m_inputHandler.HandleInput(msg, wParam, lParam))
    return 0;



char buffer[sizeof(RAWINPUT)] = {};
UINT size = sizeof(RAWINPUT);

GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, buffer, &size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
RAWINPUT    *raw = (RAWINPUT*)buffer;

if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
{
    //
}
else if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
{
    RAWKEYBOARD const &rawKB = raw->data.keyboard;
    UINT virtualKey = rawKB.VKey;
    UINT scanCode = rawKB.MakeCode;
    UINT flags = rawKB.Flags;

    // handle keyboard input and dispatch to listeners
}
```

The issue is not with the handling of the keyboard data but lies in the fact that the WM_INPUT message gets sent once, then pauses, and then gets sent regularly after the pause.

Comment: Can you show piece of code from your window procedure?

Comment: @ST3 I have posted some code.